# What is the difference between permission_classes and authentication_classes in django rest framework generic API Views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I know what permissions and authentication means. Authentication identifies the user and permissions decide what action can be done by the user. I have implemented a token authentication in django rest framework.
The problem is when i specify both permission_classes and authentication_classes in ListAPIView i cant log in to the account in browsable page.
It only works when i delete authentication classes in the view.

The following view doesn't raise any exception, but gives {
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
} response. Also not logging in.

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
```

But after deleting the authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication] the page works.

PS: curl and httpie works without any problem.

So what could be the issue here? What is the difference between those two classes?

Answer (score 0):

After removing TokenAuthentication class you are able to access the api because then drf is using session authentication and browser handles the sessions for you. When you use TokenAuthentication then you need to add token in header of request which is not done by browser. thats why you are getting  { "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }.
try this api from postman by adding the token in headers then it will work.

headers will be like:-

Authorization: Token your-token

check this for token authentication.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

and make sure user making the api call should be admin because you have specified IsAdminUser permission.